# When do we have a unique global solution to an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE I'm considering is
$$
\dot x = f(x,t)=\sin(x).
$$
With initial value $x(t_0)=x_0$.

We have the existence and uniqueness theorems for ODE's ([Picard Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)):
if $f(x,t)$ is continuous on an open neighborhood (nbhd) of $(x_0,t_0$), and $f_x(x,t)$ exists and is continuous on an open nbhd of $(x_0,t_0)$, then there is a unique solution $x(t)$ on an open nbhd of $(x_0,t_0)$ s.t. $x(t_0) = x_0$.

Is it now true that we can say that if $f$ is continuously differentiable everywhere, such as in the example above, that there exists a *unique global solution*?

Edit:
I thought that I found a counter example, but that one did not satisfy the initial value:

*I did seem to have found a counter example.
Let $x(t)$ be a solution to the above equation. Define $\overset{\sim}{x}(t) := x(t)+2\pi$. Then $\dot{\overset{\sim}{x}} = \dot x = \sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(\overset{\sim}{x})$, which would contradict the uniqueness.*

Note that $\overset{\sim}{x}$ cannot satisfy the initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way things can break down when $f$ is assumed locally Lipschitz in $x$ is via finite time blowup, for example $x'=1+x^2,x(0)=0$ which has the local solution $x=\tan(t)$. If $f$ is globally Lipschitz in $x$ then a global solution to the IVP exists and is unique. This can be shown by repeatedly constructing local solutions on successively larger subintervals which always grow by at least some minimum length (which scales something like $1/L$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant).

Your example with shifting by $2\pi$ is not relevant because that solves a different IVP, even though the ODE itself is the same.